# Rails: order using a has_many/belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was wondering if it was possible to use the find method to order the results based on a class's has_many relationship with another class. e.g.

```
# has the columns id, name
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dog_tags
end

# has the columns id, color, dog_id
class DogTags < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
end
```

and I would like to do something like this:

```
@result = DogTag.find(:all, :order => dog.name)
```

thank you.

Comment: see also how to just set the order on the relationship itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530131/rails-order-using-a-has-many-belongs-to-relationship

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to join the related table to the request.

```
@result = DogTag.find(:all, :joins => :dog, :order => 'dogs.name')
```

*Note that `dogs` is plural in the `:order` statement.*

Comment: should be DogTag.find(:all, :joins => :dog, :order => 'dogs.name') =)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm sure you know, but for anyone else, I found that the order had to be the table name as well, i.e. I had to pluarlize it: 'dogs.name' not 'dog.name'

Comment: `DogTab.where(...).joins(:dog).order('dogs.name')` yeah ! Thanks !

Answer (score 24):

In Rails 4 it should be done this way:

```
@result = DogTag.joins(:dog).order('dogs.name')
```

or with scope:

```
class DogTags < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
  scope :ordered_by_dog_name, -> { joins(:dog).order('dogs.name') }
end

@result = DogTags.ordered_by_dog_name
```

The second is easier to mock in tests as controller doesn't have to know about model details.

Comment: I tried the first but it did not work. Instead this works: `@result = DogTag.joins(:dog).order('name')`. I am using PostgreSQL, not sure if it is related