# Rails 3. sort by associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have two models: Course and ScheduledCourse.

The Course model has a name attribute.

course has_many :scheduled courses
scheduled_courses :belongs_to course

```
courses
id | name
 1 | biology
 2 | history
 3 | chemistry
 4 | literature

scheduled_courses
id | course_id 
 1 | 2
 2 | 4
 3 | 1
 4 | 2
```

How can I make an ActiveRecord query to sort the scheduled courses alphabetically?

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530131/rails-order-using-a-has-many-belongs-to-relationship

Comment: You should post what you have tried...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try...

```
ScheduledCourse.joins(:course).order('course.name')
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to call `.all` before your joins condition, like so:

```
ScheduledCourse.all.joins(:course).order('course.name')
```

Like *luacassus* said, [this answer can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530131/rails-order-using-a-has-many-belongs-to-relationship); I think the syntax in that answer is pre-Arel (ActiveRecord 3), but it'll get the job done. Hope that helps!

EDIT:

As mentioned by @FellowStranger, the correct syntax nowadays seems to be

```
ScheduledCourse.joins(:course).order('courses.name')
```

Answer (score 13):

```
ScheduledCourse.joins(:course).order('courses.name asc')
```

Note that the table name should be in plural. This code is tested.

Comment: This answer is more correct, either it should be selected as the accepted answer or the answer Ben Kreeger gave needs editing.

Comment: and is still correct in Rails 7